# cx_freeze [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, cx-freeze

When I try to use cx_freeze (python setup.py build), it creates the build, but at the bottom, I get the error message:

error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Program Files\Python35\tcl\tcl8.6'

It still creates the build, but the .exe file comes up with an error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

As I remember from my college examples, you should change your path variable to this. Just write double slashes..

```
'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\tcl\\tcl8.6'
```

Comment: I have the os.environs and the paths already have the double slashes.